# Deploy 'incomplete' when doing it from eclipse unlike when doing it directly from jboss

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, jboss

I have installed the Jboss plugin in eclipse-neon and am having some problem when deploying, more specifically, the controller mappings are not made when deploying from eclipse, it took me a while to notice why my application was not working until I saw the console closely:

**Jboss console when deployed using eclipse**

```
09:53:07,024 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) updating schema
09:53:07,026 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) schema update complete
09:53:07,062 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@5710e515] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
09:53:07,087 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 618 ms
09:53:07,090 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2  for context '/TestPJ-2'
09:53:07,611 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'deServlet'
09:53:07,611 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) FrameworkServlet 'deServlet': initialization started
09:53:07,613 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'deServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Apr 05 09:53:07 CDT 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
09:53:07,613 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deServlet-servlet.xml]
09:53:07,659 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
09:53:07,728 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Mapped URL path [/pages/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
09:53:07,859 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) FrameworkServlet 'deServlet': initialization completed in 248 ms
09:53:07,860 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /TestPJ-2
09:53:07,880 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "TestPJ-2.war" (runtime-name : "TestPJ-2.war")
```

**Jboss console when deploying directly**

```
09:28:32,619 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) updating schema
09:28:32,621 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) schema update complete
09:28:32,802 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@3fb339bb] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
09:28:32,915 INFO  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5481c4f2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3bf500d5, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5162956e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@37b243f2, com.pier.security.filters.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter@10d418a7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@49ee8f82, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@48cd3f9d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@274b25f9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2624ef4d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@258c1ccf, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2ed083b3, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@157aedd3, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@614ad1d3]
09:28:32,946 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2388 ms
09:28:32,980 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2  for context '/TestPJ-2'
09:28:33,780 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'deServlet'
09:28:33,780 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) FrameworkServlet 'deServlet': initialization started
09:28:33,781 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'deServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Apr 05 09:28:33 CDT 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
09:28:33,782 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deServlet-servlet.xml]
09:28:33,850 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
09:28:33,906 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Mapped URL path [/pages/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
09:28:33,930 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Mapped "{[/persons/{name}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public static com.pier.rest.Person com.pier.rest.PersonRestService.getPerson(java.lang.String)
09:28:33,931 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Mapped "{[/persons],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public static java.util.List<com.pier.rest.Person> com.pier.rest.PersonRestService.getPersons()
09:28:33,931 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Mapped "{[/refresh],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.pier.security.controller.AuthenticationRestController.refreshAndGetAuthenticationToken(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
09:28:33,931 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Mapped "{[/login],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.pier.security.controller.AuthenticationRestController.authenticateUser(com.pier.security.AuthenticationRequest,org.springframework.mobile.device.Device)
09:28:33,931 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Mapped "{[/protected],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.pier.security.controller.MethodProtectedRestController.getProtectedGreeting()
09:28:33,932 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Mapped "{[/user],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.pier.security.JwtUser com.pier.security.controller.UserRestController.getauthenticatedUser(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
09:28:34,289 INFO  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@224abc36, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2e6245fa, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@c035836, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@61005d5d, com.pier.security.filters.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter@5a54f1f1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@4589b9ca, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@71ddefb7, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@18f8559c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@e2c6c5d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@347b117a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@395ad326, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3320a193, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@c13469b]
09:28:34,326 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) FrameworkServlet 'deServlet': initialization completed in 546 ms
09:28:34,327 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /TestPJ-2
09:28:34,372 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "TestPJ-2.war" (runtime-name : "TestPJ-2.war")
```

I'm using the maven plugin also, if I copy the exact same war that's built when running "clean install" through eclipse's maven plugin to the "deployments" folder in jboss directory the application works fine, any ideas why?

**Update:** added pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestPJ</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestPJ</artifactId>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\PC\workspace\TestPJ\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
        <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Users\PC\workspace\TestPJ\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>C:\Users\PC\workspace\TestPJ\target\classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <springsecurity.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <version>2</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: I can not find `incomplete` or `error` in logs you have shared. All are `info`.

Comment: well there are no logs, apparently it just skips the mapping of controllers, but see how the lines of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` are missing in the first log, I would rather have an error message because i'd know where to start from.

Comment: have you removed the JBOSS server from eclipse and add it again & checked. Some times there are issues.

Comment: yep, several times.

Comment: Is this the JBoss Tools plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace? Can you share your pom.xml as well, please?

Comment: @JonSampson yes it is that same plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to have a more automatized process to hot deploy the code changes, hence my intent to add the project using jboss server plugin.
In the end a workaround was to deploy using maven's jboss plugin instead of "Adding/Removing" the project in Eclipse's server plugin.

**pom.xml:**

```
<plugins>
    <!-- configure WAR stuff etc -->
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                <warName>${plugin.war.warName}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    <!-- this is important!! -->
            <plugin>            
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    <!-- jboss plugin important too!!-->        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${artifactId}-${project.version}.ear</filename>
                 <port>8999</port>  <!-- you change it following what you have on your server config -->
                 <filename>${plugin.war.warName}.${project.packaging}</filename>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>
```

then execute or run the project with these parameters under Run Configurations: `clean install jboss-as:deploy`

Answer (score 2):

Okay I'll take a stab. This sounds as though Eclipse isn't creating the same WAR file as Maven - your project's Deployment Assembly configuration could be wrong.

Verify JBoss is deploying a bum version by checking to see that the `deploy` directory contains an incomplete, exploded war file (an uncompressed directory in WAR format). You might note if you are missing classes in WEB-INF/classes (for example the `com.pier.rest.PersonRestService`)

If so (or regardless), verify the Eclipse configuration:

1. Right Click on your Project and select Properties
2. Click Deployment Assembly and ensure that all your classes are being added to the structure correctly. My test project has something like:

> ```
> Source                         Deploy Path
> /src/main/java                 WEB-INF/classes
> /src/main/resources            WEB-INF/classes
> /src/main/webapp               /
> /target/m2e-wtp/web-resources  /
> Maven Dependencies             WEB-INF/lib
> ```

I assume you will find the above to be screwed up somehow, as Eclipse is using this configuration to deploy to JBoss.

Comment: I'm using the same war file that's created under the "target" folder when building with Eclipse's maven plugin, for both deploys I'm using the same war file, unless the Jboss tools plugin is deploying the project directly. You just gave me a clue of where to start, although both deploys end up under "deployments" folder I will compare the before and after war, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I just checked inside the two war files and the one deployed with eclipse has an empty WEB-INF folder

Comment: Well at this point I can't duplicate the behavior. I have built my test war file with maven and selected "Mark as Deployable" from the right click menu in Eclipse. After right clicking again on the war and doing Run As > Run on Server, I see the same exact war file (WEB-INF and all) deployed. Eclipse Neon, JBoss Tools 4.4.3, Wildfly 10.1.0.